# Как вывести все HTML теги используя beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Для парсинга сайтов я использую библиотеку BeautifulSoup и мне нужно вывести все теги li, но выводиться только один(у этого тега нет класса). Как это сделать?

Вот код:

```
page = requests.get(url)
print(page.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

result = soup.find("div", class_='casualties')
print(result.div.ul.li.string)
```

Comment: Читать документацию BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот наглядный пример выводит все теги li. Метод `find`, который вы использовали, - возвращает первый найденный тег. Метод `find_all` возвращает список всех найденных тегов, который потом можно перебрать циклом.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '\ 
                  'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '\
                  'Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36'
}


def parse_all_li(url):
    response = requests.get(url)  # headers можно передать сюда как параметр
    # Помогает, если сайт подозревает что запрос сделал бот.
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

    for li in soup.find_all('li'):
        print(li)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse_all_li('http://htmlbook.ru/faq/kak-sozdat-tablitsu-v-html5-i-ukazat-ee-parametry-cherez')
```

Comment: Советую больше гуглить, прежде чем задавать вопросы на этом проекте. По вашему вопросу "как вывести все теги beautifulsoup", сразу нашёл сайт с аналогичным кодом:
https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/scraping-webpages-in-python-with-beautiful-soup-search-and-dom-modification--cms-28276

Answer (score 1):

```
result = soup.find_all("div", class_='casualties')
print(result.div.ul.li.string)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]